# Storing csv file columns as an array in python

Tags: python, list, csv, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have a csv file containing two columns. I want to create 2 seperate arrays for each of the column in python. How do I proceed with doing that? Any suggestions would greatly help. i have attached a snippet of how my csv file looks like.

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your post and put there sample of your CSV file (with correct formatting)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend seeing [one of these threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+csv+to+array) and looking at [how the search functionality works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

To load the CSV file into two lists:

```py
import csv

col1 = []
col2 = []
with open("your_file.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    next(reader)  # skip headers

    for line in reader:
        col1.append(float(line[0]))
        col2.append(float(line[1]))

print(col1)
print(col2)
```

Prints:

```py
[-7.66e-06, -7.6e-06, -7.53e-06]
[17763.0, 2853.0, 3694.0]
```